# How can I embed a private vimeo video in a React Native app?

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, vimeo

For embedding Vimeo videos on the web, I just need to set up my Vimeo video to allow embedding for a specific URL (eg. www.myapp.com) and then it works.  When I try to view the same video in a React Native app with a web view I get a `NSUrlErrorDomain` exception.

I've gone through the Vimeo documentation and can't find the answer. Is it possible to do this?  Or do I need to make my videos public for it to work?

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/LXVimeoKit

Comment: hii..did u get any proper solution. i need the same thing in my app.. can u pls help

Answer (score 3):

Domain privacy is on and just like that;

```
<WebView source={{uri: 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/videoid',headers: {"Referer":"https://yourwebsite.com"}}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Domain privacy for Vimeo embeds requires the HTTP referer to be passed back to the iframe so the Player can determine if the domain where its embedded can play back the video. If you're on a local page without an HTTP referer, then the domain privacy feature will not work.

You'll need to set the video's embed privacy to "Embed anywhere", or use direct video file links (as a PRO or Business member) with the platform's native media player. More info here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-player-links

Comment: Vimeo Domain Privacy is just checking Referer URL. There is no need to set it Embed anywhere. Only send Referer to video and it will open and play.